# multi channel sound playback with MonoTouch

Tags: audio, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer

I have a MonoTouch AVAudioPLayer that i want to play whenever an event occurs.

My code looks like this:

```
...
AVAudioPlayer player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
...

public void handleEvent(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
    player.Play();
}
```

But if the event occurs again before the player is finished playing the sound, it will not fire again, waiting until the sound is complete before accepting another `.Play()` command.

How can get the sound to fire regardless of whether it is already playing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AVAudioPlayer` isn't a good choice for sound effects--it's meant more for making a music player.  (It also pauses any music playing in the background like iTunes or Pandora)

Try using system sounds, see here: [How can I play a sound on the iPhone using MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468393/how-can-i-play-a-sound-on-the-iphone-using-monotouch)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, i was hoping i could avoid it so i wouldn't have to bother with a relatively exotic encoding like .caf, but it'll do.

Comment: For future reference : you can make a CAF file by converting the sound to an .aif, then simply renaming the file extension to .caf